# cat-like functionality under Fuchsia OS command line

Tags: fuchsia

In the first command the `>` has the output of the `ls` command go to `/data/result.txt`. In the second command you see that size of the file is `229`.

```
$ ls > /data/result.txt
$ ls /data/result.txt
-      229 /data/result.txt
```

Using the Fuchsia OS emulator there are a number of programs that are on the target system. See the reformatted list. `ls` gives a directory listing. `hw` is a modified version of `hello_world_cpp`. From the collection of programs on the system, is there one that can be used to display the contents of  `/data/result.txt`?

```
$ ls /boot/bin                            -  1   286720 hid                      -  1    76176 ps
d  2        0 .                           -  1   201328 hw                       -  1   290832 ptysvc                                                                                                                             
-  1   221184 app                         -  1    53248 i2c                      -  1    70768 pwrbtn-monitor                                                                                                                             
-  1   314616 audio                       -  1   162024 i2cutil                  -  1   270272 run-vc                                                                                                                             
-  1   192024 backlight                   -  1   376848 ihda                     -  1  1142800 runtests                                                                                                                             
-  1    90128 biotime                     -  1  2871312 install-disk-image       -  1  3035736 rust_test_adapter                                                                                                                             
-  1     8280 blktest                     -  1  2035712 iochk                    -  1   320896 sdio                                                                                                                             
-  1  5353744 blobfs                      -  1  2012496 iotime                   -  1   212856 serial-test                                                                                                                                                     
-  1   331792 bootsvc                     -  1  1433896 isolated_devmgr          -  1   188840 sh                                                                                                                                                     
-  1    49984 clkctl                      -  1    16888 kcounter                 -  1    63800 signal                                                                                                                                                     
-  1    50208 clock                       -  1    63784 kill                     -  1     8264 spawn                                                                                                                                                     
-  1   892976 cmd                         -  1    65536 killall                  -  1   114192 spiutil                                                                                                                                                     
-  1  2681408 component_manager           -  1    45316 kilo                     -  1  2033040 storage-metrics                                                                                                                                                     
-  1   286736 console                     -  1    69632 kstats                   -  1   335912 svchost                                                                                                                                                                                     
-  1   880792 cpuctl                      -  1    53248 kstress                  -  1     8328 syscall-check                                                                                                                                                                                     
-  1    12624 crasher                     -  1    61456 ktrace                   -  1   278544 sysinfo                                                                                                                                                                                     
-  1   228240 dd                          -  1    16400 loadgen                  -  1  1315208 sysmem_connector                                                                                                                                                                                     
-  1   290832 ddk-schedule-work-perf      -  1  1220608 lsblk                    -  1     8280 tee-test                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-  1   274448 device-name-provider        -  1   842704 lsdev                    -  1    70368 thermal-cli                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-  1   217120 df                          -  1    55280 lspwr                    -  1    77824 threads                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-  1  2469904 disk-inspect                -  1    76512 lsusb                    -  1    73760 top                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-  1   880672 display-test                -  1   172400 lz4                      -  1    81920 trace-benchmark
-  1    63776 dlog                        -  1    82112 memgraph                 -  1    90112 trace-example
-  1  2908472 driver_host                 -  1  2494704 minfs                    -  1   131072 umount
-  1  4038384 driver_manager              -  1   565264 miscsvc                  -  1   842688 unbind
-  1   867040 driverctl                   -  1   132144 mkfs                     -  1   875448 usb-fwloader
-  1     8288 driverinfo                  -  1    21120 mkfs-msdosfs             -  1   258120 usbctl
-  1   131968 fsck                        -  1   135424 mount                    -  1  2581032 virtual-console
-  1    36864 fsck-msdosfs                -  1   126976 mutex_pi_exerciser       -  1    67928 vmaps
-  1   684048 fshost                      -  1   113432 nand-loader              -  1    72032 vmos
-  1  2052112 fvm-check                   -  1   909312 nand-util                -  1   917504 waitfor
-  1    98304 gpt                         -  1   210008 netsvc                   -  1     8264 watch
-  1    74016 handles                     -  1    16624 ping                     -  1    45568 xdc-test
-  1   149728 hello_world_rust
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cat` program is provided by the `//third_party/sbase:cat` target.

The `bringup` product creates a minimal image that does not include this target (list of products [here](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/master/products/)). To use `cat` in the `bringup` product:

- Option 1: Explicitly include the `//bundles:tools` target, which depends on `cat` and some other basic tools.

  ```
   $ fx set bringup.x64 --with //bundles:tools
   $ fx build
   $ fx qemu
   $ cat -v
   usage: cat [-u] [file ...]
  ```
- Option 2: Explicitly include only `cat`

  ```
   $ fx set bringup.x64 --with //third_party/sbase:cat
   $ fx build
   $ fx qemu
   $ cat -v
   usage: cat [-u] [file ...]
  ```

For the other products from `core` upwards, the `//bundles:tools` target, and thus `cat` is included in the package universe by default, as can be seen in the declaration of `core` ([link](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/c9b4277368ec32422c18fdd7fca98ff90877489f/products/core.gni#95)). Thus, it will be pulled on demand, as described [here](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/concepts/packages/package_update).